# No logro entender un problema de Javascript

Tags: javascript

El problema es el siguiente:

Escribe un programa que use `console.log` para imprimir todos los números de 1 a 100, con dos excepciones.

Para números divisibles por 3, imprime "Fizz" en lugar del número, y para los números divisibles por 5 (y no 3), imprime "Buzz" en su lugar.

Cuando tengas eso funcionando, modifica tu programa para imprimir "FizzBuzz", para números que sean divisibles entre 3 y 5 (y aún imprimir "Fizz" o "Buzz" para números divisibles por solo uno de ellos)."

logre hacerlo hasta el paso dos con `else if()` pero no logré hacer el paso 3 así que fui a la solución del problema, pero no logro entender cómo es que muestra 'fizzbuzz' en los números que son divisibles entre 3 y 5 , entiendo casi todo pero menos ese punto.

```js
for (let n = 1; n <= 100; n++) {
  let output = "";
  if (n % 3 == 0) output += "Fizz";
  if (n % 5 == 0) output += "Buzz";
  console.log(output || n);
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
Ejemplo para n = 15 // divisible entre 3 y 5

output = ""

si n es divisible entre 3 output += "Fizz";

El valor actual de output es "Fizz";

si n es divisible entre 5 output += "Buzz";

El valor actual de output es "FizzBuzz";

Aquí viene la parte rara `output || n`

El operador || evalúa si su lado izquierdo no tiene valor, 
si no lo tiene entonces elige su lado derecho.

De esa forma en los números que no son divisibles ni por 3 ni por 5
se imprime el número. Si el número es divisible por 3 o 5 o ambos entonces
se imprime Fizz, Buzz o FizzBuzz; que es el  valor de output.
```

Answer (score 2):

Si se fija en el programa, dentro del ciclo for hay una variable (output) , esta variable es acumulativa . Esto quiere decir que si n es divisible entre 3 entonces la línea que se va a ejecutar es:

```
if (n % 3 == 0) output += "Fizz";
```

por lo que ahora la variable output="Fizz"
luego si también es divisible por 5 entonces se ejecuta esta línea:

```
 if (n % 5 == 0) output += "Buzz";
```

Y si recuerda output valía "Fizz" y ahora se le esta agregando "Buzz" por lo que ahora
output vale "fizzBuzz".
Espero le haya quedado claro.

Comment: Creo que tambien le serviría aclarar que el operador += agrega el valor al valor del mismo, y en caso de ser cadenas se juntan, sin reemplazarlo.

Comment: Gracias Rirchad  ya logré comprender ,pensé que  la variable output se remplazaba cada ves que coincida con la  condición  pero gracias a Ange  se que las cadenas se juntan y no se reemplazan ,Gracias muchachos